# What better way to structure my database?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, dynamic, rdbms

Need to identify the best way to contemplate this scenario :
The User can enter the system which fields he wants and what type of field

Example:

```
ID;Key;Type;
01;Name;Varchar;
02;Date;DateTime;
03;Gender;byte;
```

Then a 'tbRegister' table must store the information of the document registered by the user using the fields that it created.

*Exemple:*

```
 Guid;DocumentID;Fild_Name;Fild_Date;Fild_Gender;CreateOn; CreateBy;
das215sa-15d1a-2d56as1;1;João;21/01/2001;1;30/11/2013 10:00:00; msantiago;
```

I also see a relationship between these tables. Something like:

FildByDocument:

```
idFild;DocumentID;
01;1;
02;1;
03;1;
01;2;
```

How would this in practice?
Like to meet a good structure. For such systems may contain very different types of documents

Got an exact example of what I wanted:

[image]

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do something like

```
Table_One_User

User_ID;INT; IDENTITY(1,1);  --<-- Primary Key
01;Name;Varchar;
02;Date;DateTime;
03;Gender;byte;


Table_Two_File

DocumentID;      --<-- Use INT not GUID (GUID is Not a good choice for Primary Key)
Fild_Name;
Fild_Date;
CreateOn; 
CreateBy;  Foreign Key --<-- Referencing to User_ID column in Table_One
                          -- You dont need to record Gender here  you have 
                          -- this information in Table one
```

Comment: hanks, But I never know which fields the User will register then how would the table Table_Two_File     Sorry, but I think it is not very clear to me

Comment: 'm Brazilian my english sucks :(;
I never know the names of the fields would have something totally dynamic, How would your example in practice?

Comment: no its ok your english is fine pal. do you mean Users can add data to any field how would you know which field they are adding data to ??

Comment: There has to be some kind of relationship with id 'field'.:

Comment: @msantiago yes store the User_ID in CreatedBy field and this will be the reference.

Comment: But as this table would have these fields without knowing what they are?

Comment: You are helping me a lot, Thanks you

Comment: Got an exact example of what I wanted, Have a look at the image of the post. Thanks

Comment: Your help was very useful, They said that this is not the best way to do this.(MichaC speak : "Hint: an RDBMs can handle any kind of relations between different tables, you don't have to "create dynamic columns" ) What did he mean?

Comment: the way he is suggesting its not dynamic column but its a third table which further normalize the data inside your database which personally I think is a better way to do such operations. I dont know what your business requirements are, when designing a database you should always keep the business model in picture and design your database around it to suit it without compromising Database performance. I guess I have spoken too much all I am saying is its only you who knows how files are added and who can add who should be able to add files and who shouldnt, so for any other person to give

Comment: so for any other person who doesnt have all this information it will not be possible for them to give you the right advice. My suggestion will be to read more about "Best Practices For Designing Database" and then decide your self what suits you best. :)